# Liferay Service Builder not updating BLOB

Tags: hibernate, liferay, liferay-service-builder

I'm trying to get my Liferay Service to update a column of the type BLOB. Persisting the respective entity works fine, so does deleting. Updating does not throw an exception, but simply comes back with the old value is the BLOB-typed field.

My setup:

- Liferay 6.1 CE GA3 bundled with Tomcat
- Liferay Plugins SDK for 6.1 GA3
- 5.6.19 MySQL Community Server
- hibernate3.jar (from https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-42478)

My steps so far in Eclipse:

-create a new Liferay Portlet Project

-create a new Liferay Service Builder (package com.test, namespace my_service)

-edit service.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_6_1_0.dtd">
<service-builder package-path="com.test">
    <author>fe</author>
    <namespace>my_service</namespace>
    <entity name="Foo" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
        <column name="fooId" type="long" primary="true" />
        <column name="companyId" type="long" />
        <column name="userId" type="long" />
        <column name="userName" type="String" />
        <column name="createDate" type="Date" />
        <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date" />
        <column name="field1" type="Blob" />
        <order by="asc">
            <order-column name="fooId" />
        </order>
    </entity>
</service-builder>
```

-ant build-service

-edit FooLocalServiceImpl.java:

```
public Foo addFoo(User user, String data, ServiceContext serviceContext) throws PortalException, SystemException {
    Date now = new Date();
    long fooId = counterLocalService.increment(Foo.class.getName());
    Foo foo = fooPersistence.create(fooId);
    foo.setCompanyId(user.getCompanyId());
    foo.setUserId(user.getUserId());
    foo.setCreateDate(serviceContext.getCreateDate(now));
    foo.setModifiedDate(serviceContext.getModifiedDate(now));
    Blob blob = null;
    try {
        blob = new SerialBlob(data.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    foo.setField1(blob);
    super.addFoo(foo);
    return foo;
}

public Foo updateFoo(User user, long fooId, String data, ServiceContext serviceContext) throws PortalException, SystemException {
    Date now = new Date();
    Foo foo = FooLocalServiceUtil.fetchFoo(fooId);
    foo.setCachedModel(false);
    foo.setModifiedDate(serviceContext.getModifiedDate(now));
    Blob blob = null;
    try {
        blob = new SerialBlob(data.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    foo.setField1(blob);
    super.updateFoo(foo);
    return foo;
}
```

-ant build-service

-remove duplicate entry from portlet-hbm.xml

-edit view.jsp:

```
<%
    User user = PortalUtil.getUser(request);
    ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(request);
    Foo foo = FooLocalServiceUtil.addFoo(user, "This is some data", serviceContext);
    long fooId = foo.getFooId();
%>
We added a Foo (<%=foo.getModifiedDate().getTime() %>)<br>
<%
    Blob blob = FooLocalServiceUtil.fetchFoo(fooId).getField1();
    byte[] bdata = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
    String data = new String(bdata);        
%>
It contains the data "<%=data%>"<br>
<%
    foo = FooLocalServiceUtil.updateFoo(user, fooId, "This is some updated data", serviceContext);
    fooId = foo.getFooId();
%>
Now we updated the Foo (<%=foo.getModifiedDate().getTime() %>)<br>
<%
    blob = FooLocalServiceUtil.fetchFoo(fooId).getField1();
    bdata = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
    data = new String(bdata);       
%>
It contains the data "<%=data%>"<br>
```

-set portal properties:

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
```

-Deploy portlet via Eclipse

Unfortunately the BLOB column doesn't seem to get an update, while the modifiedDate gets one.

When I check the DB I get:

```
mysql> select * from my_service_Foo;
+-------+-----------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| fooId | companyId | userId | userName | createDate          | modifiedDate        | field1            |
+-------+-----------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|     1 |     10153 |  10406 |          | 2014-06-24 07:06:37 | 2014-06-24 07:06:37 | This is some data |
+-------+-----------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: You say "remove duplicate entry from portlet-hbm.xml" - can you elaborate on that? I'm not aware that it's necessary to edit any of those generated files

Comment: When I run "ant build-service" the 2nd time I get a duplicate entry of `<class name="com.test.model.FooField1BlobModel" table="my_service_Foo" lazy="true">[...]`. This only seems to happen when there's a BLOB column.

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem, but the number of scriplets is overwhelming =(

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue.I made few changes in the update method call.

Here is the change you can do in your **updateFoo** method

> super.updateFoo(foo,false);

second argument in your method call will set the Boolean merge to false which will forcefully execute **session.saveOrUpdate** statement and will skip session.merge(foo) statement in upadate() method of **BatchSessionImpl**.